# Three.js - Double sided plane one side reversed

Tags: three.js, textures

I used the method of pushing faces to geometry to achieve double sided plane.

```
for (var i=0, len=geometry.faces.length; i<len; i++) {
    var face = geometry.faces[i].clone();
    face.materialIndex = 1;
    geometry.faces.push(face);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push(geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i].slice(0));
}
```

but one side is reversed here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bN8ZH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put two planes back-to-back, the best way is like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(80, 116, 20, 20);

var geometry2 = geometry.clone();
geometry2.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY( Math.PI ) );

THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( geometry, geometry2, 1 );
```

When you do so, make sure the material for each plane has `material.side = THREE.FrontSide`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bN8ZH/1/

three.js r.63

Comment: This doubles the vertices, I need to do some heavy transformations and this approach will double the calculations

Comment: No, it will not. Both approaches have the same number of faces, normals, vertex normals, uv's -- only the list of vertices is different. You can call `geometry.mergeVertices()` if you want, and the vertices will be the same.

Comment: Even if it looked good, when animation started it was a mess, when I can share the project I'll let you know; for now I'll just flip the image :)

Comment: Yes, `CanvasRenderer` has its limitations.